# How to show all columns on a graph in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
229 2014-03-11                     6071           
230 2014-03-12                     6071   12 (1.2)
231 2014-03-13                     6080           
232 2014-03-14                     6090           
233 2014-03-15                     6096           
234 2014-03-16                     6084           
235 2014-03-17                     6096           
236 2014-03-18                     6104           
237 2014-03-19                     6111           
238 2014-03-20                     6123           
239 2014-03-21                     6121           
240 2014-03-22                     6141 15 (2.0.1)
241 2014-03-23                     6146           
242 2014-03-24                     6153
```

I need to plot date vs second column and at the same time show software version release on the graph.

I've tried to use `plot()` function but it only shows second column and I can't figure out how to add the second one.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  value = 1:5,
  label = c(NA, NA, "a", NA, "b")
)

# plot
plot(df$x, df$value)

# add labels
text(df$x, df$value, df$label, pos = 4)
```

[image]